# How to multiply result from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got this code:

```
$res = $db->fetchAssoc($db->query('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `last_logged`>'. $today));
$stats['log_today'] = end($res);
```

I want something like this. If the result from SELECT COUNT is for example 10, the script will show 6 times more so 60 not 10.

Please help me.

Comment: use `6*count(id)` in the `select`

Answer (score 1):

just add multi 6 in the SELECT part.

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) * 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do math in the select statement in mysql.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html

E.g.: `SELECT 6*10;` or `` SELECT 6 * COUNT(`id`) ... ``

Answer (score 0):

update your query like this(if '6' is static:

```
....SELECT COUNT(`id`) * 6 FROM `users` WHERE `last_logged`......
```